# Let $a,b\in\Bbb{N}.$ Show that there is a minimum natural number of the form $a-b m,$ where $m \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, solution-verification

Let $a,b\in\Bbb{N}.$ Show that there is a minimum natural number of the form $a-b m,$ where $m \in \Bbb{Z}$.

If I define the set $T=\{a-bm \in \Bbb N \mid a,b \in \mathbb{N}, m \in\mathbb{Z}\}$, it's clear that $T\neq\emptyset$ because $1\in T$ and $T\subset\mathbb{N}$. Then by Well-ordering theorem $T$ has a minimum.

Is this right or I have to do something more?

Comment: This is not right. Why do you think $1$ must be in $T$? What if $a=-3$ and $b=6$? I suggest you write out what $T$ looks like for several examples. Then you can see how to use the well ordering theorem.

Comment: @EthanBolker $a\in\mathbb{N}$ and we can write $1= 1-b*0=$ in particular if we take $m=0$ T is containing all natural numbers

Comment: If $a=15$ and $b=6$ then whatever the value of $m$, $a-mb$ will be divisible by $3$ so will never be $1$.

Comment: @EthanBolker and if we define $T=\{a-bm \in \Bbb N \mid a,b \in \mathbb{N}, m \in\mathbb{Z}\}$  but only taking the natural numbers in the form a-bm

Comment: See the answer from @ACheca

Answer (score 2):

Reading your answer and your comment I think you're misunderstanding an important part of the problem: when you say let $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ you're fixing these values. For the rest of the problem, $a,b$ are fixed. So the definition of $T$, which is dependent on $a,b$ should actually be:

$$ T_{a,b}= \{ a-bm\in \mathbb{N} | m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

Note that in your definition of $T$, it seems that $a,b$ could be variable, and I think that was what made you think $1\in T$, when this is false in general. In the expression $a-bm$ everything is fixed except $m$.

With this in mind, try again the same argument you were trying before, having in mind that in general $1$ doesn't have to be in $T$.